# Using EntityFunctions without entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime

I have a Linq query:

```
people.Where(x => EntityFunctions.DiffHours(x.CreateDate, dtMatch) > 0)
```

that does only work within `Linq 2 Entities`.

How do I make this method run without Entities?

What I've tried so far:

```
people.Where(x => (x.CreateDate - dtMatch).TotalHours  > 0)
```

... seems to give a different result

Comment: people.Where(x => (x.CreateDate - dtMatch).TotalHours  > 0)  usually works. Can you tell us what's the difference between those two statements you saw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: To make the 2 statements equivalent change `TotalHours` to `Math.Floor((x.CreateDate - dtMatch).TotalHours)`

---

```
people.Where(x => Math.Floor((x.CreateDate - dtMatch).TotalHours) > 0)
```

The `TotalHours` will return a decimal. So if there was 30 minutes between the 2 dates then `0.5` would be returned. As .5 is greater than 0 the above returns true. If you want whole hours change it to Math.Floor(TotalHours) instead of `TotalHours`. This will round it down to the next largest integer.

---

[EntityFunctions.DiffHours](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395540(v=vs.110).aspx) - This returns an integer representing the whole number of hours, so if it was 30 min. difference then 0 would be the result.

Comment: Using Hours gets only the Hours component which is always less than 24. That's a bad idea!

Comment: Good answer btw

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you should consider the case if dtMatch is over CreateDate and the case if it is under:

```
people.Where(x => Math.Abs((x.CreateDate - dtMatch).TotalHours) > 0)
```